# How to get Acces Token for Google API using Asp.Net MVC 5 Web and OWIN / Katana

Tags: google-api, asp.net-mvc-5, google-contacts-api, owin, katana

Having a Asp.Net MVC 5 Web Role using OWIN Katana Components for OAuth and OpenId. Enabled Google Authentication support inside *Startup.Auth.cs* (provided by default MVC 5 template).

Everything works fine until authentication but not sure how to request authorizaion token as mentioned here [Google Contacts API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#running_the_sample_code).

Please share pointers to samples or documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Google has multiple authentication protocols.  The one implemented in Katana v2.0 is not OAuth2, so there is no authorization token.  It's only useful for having google confirm who the user is, it does not give you access to their resources.

In Katana v2.1-rc1 (coming this month) support is being added for Google's OAuth2 protocol.
https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/0eb10848ae18a5f339e7fde8ff1e877242e944dc